# spark-java package how to use Spark from Scala?

Tags: scala, spark-java

I'm willing to use the spark-java package from my Scala application

how to convert the Java call written in the spark-java documentation:

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
```

into Scala ?

Thanks a lot

Christian

Comment: Did the answer really solve your problem? I see you accepted the answer. Would you mind clarifying, please? `spark-java` and Apache Spark is two different types of projects, one used as a micro web framework and another for big data processing and analytics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you want to convert? It will work the same. Scala and Java both run on a JVM. Plus, if you really want to modify, you can fork their repo and change the code.

But I don't see why you would want to. Can you please elaborate why you would want to do this?? By the way, just for reference :
Spark is mainly written in scala.

If you want to use spark in scala, I suggest you use spark scala : https://github.com/apache/spark

Comment: This is not a correct answer as `spark-java` http://sparkjava.com/ is a different project than Apache Spark. The question was to use the micro web framework `spark-java` in Scala but the answer provided here is to use Apache Spark, which is a Data Processing and Analytics tool.